# YouTube API List Video used shortly after Insert returns no video

Tags: php, youtube-api

The use case i have here, that was working for close to 2 years is as follows.

- Video is uploaded to users YouTube Channel.
- After the upload we get back a Video ID from YouTube.
- Immediately following that we attempt to set the videos Thumbnail

This process has worked for a while now, and while we have encountered issue before we've not encountered this issue. (The last issue we had was related to using YouTube's PHP Library to set the thumbnail, so we switched to cURL which solved that problem.)

The Video does upload, so I'm not going to post that code as that works fine.
Here is how the thumbnail is being set:

```
$thumbnail_path = realpath($PathToImage);
$data = [
    'filedata' => new CURLFile($thumbnail_path, 'image/jpeg', basename($thumbnail_path)),
];      
$curl = curl_init();
// This just us the token data that the cURL requests uses, don't think too hard about it
$token = $CustomYouTubeCredenetialsClass->BuildClientAccessTokenArray();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$token['access_token'],
]);
// Here $VideoId is set by the video upload process, we store this value so i can assure you that it is set and set correctly
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set?videoId='.$VideoId.'&key='.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$response_json = json_decode($response, true);
```

This will return the notFound (404) error from the YouTube Thumbnails API documentation.

Furthermore doing requests like

```
// This is a valid YouTube client using the users access token
$YouTubeClient->videos->listVideos("processingDetails,status", array('id' => $VideoId));
```

Will not return the video id matching the one we provided and

```
$response = $YouTubeClient->channels->listChannels(
    'contentDetails',
    [
        'mine' => true
    ]
);                    
$uploads_playlist = $response['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'];
$response = $YouTubeClient->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems(
    'snippet,status,processingDetails',
    [
        'pageToken' => null,
        'maxResults' => 10,
        'playlistId' => $uploads_playlist
    ]
);
```

This will list the latest 10 videos uploaded to this channel, however, this will also not include the video just uploaded via the API.

I was under the impression that even a processing video SHOULD still be returned in this results, especially since processDetails is a part you can request. Because it doesn't, other processed that we have which are designed to periodically check the status of a YouTube Video (so that they can be posted to other platforms, for example) can now fail because it won't find the video.

If you were to wait about 5 seconds, the video will then be returned in all of the queries (and you can also set the thumbnail) however this kind of delay isn't documented at all and was only very recently introduced as an issue.